# PowerShell parameters with special characters

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script to send an email, and some of the parameters may contains special characters, such as % and &.

```
powershell.exe .\sendmail.ps1 -to "user@something.com" -body "Special character & causing trouble." -subject 'PowerShell email'
```

This gives the following error:

```
Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

I have tried escaping the & with `. But the parameter will still not be correctly included in the script.

I am looking for a way to make sure the parameters will be correctly passed on to the script, including special characters. I am thinking about using encodedcommand, or perhaps placing the parameters in an xml file.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Here is the script I am using:

```
param (
    [string]$body = "",
    [string]$subject = $(throw "-subject is required."),
    [string]$attachment = "",
    [string]$to = ""
)

Try
{
    $o = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
}
Catch
{
    $o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
}

$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)

$mail.subject = "Auto Build Test"

$mail.body = $body

#for multiple email, use semi-colon ; to separate
$mail.To = $to
$mail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$mail.Display(0)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try call the script in this way and let me know:

```
powershell.exe -command "& .\sendmail.ps1 -to user@something.com -body 'Special character & causing trouble.' -subject 'PowerShell email'"
```

Comment: Wow, that actually seems to work! Even with other special characters. Apparently, I have been missing the "Call operator"

Answer (score 6):

simply use `'` instead of `"` to disable expansion

`powershell.exe .\sendmail.ps1 -to "user@something.com" -body 'Special character & causing trouble.' -subject 'PowerShell email'`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work.
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: this is working fine on PS V2 & PS V3 your probleme is elswere maybe in your sendmail.ps1. Show your script if you want more help. This is what i ran `PS>Send-MailMessage -to "www@yyy.com" -body 'Special character & causing trouble.' -subject 'PowerShell email' -from 'titi@toto.com'`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have included the script in my question.

Comment: is there any good reason to use outlook via COM instead of using the powershell cmdlet [send-mailmessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) ??

Comment: Unfortunately, there are reasons beyond my authority dictating the need to use Outlook via COM instead of send-mailmessage.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint. I had a problem passing = symbol to the PS script from a .BAT file and I resolved it by enclosing it with single quotes.